# Multiple level nesting in YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm trying to use YAML to create list of all stored procs used in an application and from where they are called. I envisioned something like below but I think YAML does not allow multiple level nesting.

```
access_log:
  stored_proc: getsomething
    uses:
      usedin: some->bread->crumb
      usedin: something else here
  stored_proc: anothersp
    uses:
      usedin: blahblah

reporting:
  stored_proc: reportingsp
    uses:
      usedin: breadcrumb
```

Is there a way to do this in YAML and if not, what other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's exactly how I've used nested levels in YAML for configuration files for perl scripts. [This YAML Tutorial](http://rhnh.net/2011/01/31/yaml-tutorial) might be a good reference for you on how to handle the structure you want in Ruby.

I think your problem is trying to mix types. I suggest revising like this:

```
reporting: 
  stored_procs: 
    - 
      name: reportingsp
      uses: 
        usedin: breadcrumb
    - 
      name: secondProc
      uses: 
        usedin: something_else
```

Comment: hmm that tutorial doesn't show deep nesting. If I load the above structured yaml in my ruby script, it gives me an error while loading the yaml file.

Comment: I've definitely used multiple levels of nesting. What I notice, that I have not done, is that you have a mix of things. e.g. stored_proc with a value and more nested beneath. That may be the issue.

Comment: yeah, thats the issue. I want deep nesting so everything gets aligned. I guess that isn't possible with yaml

Comment: How is this the right answer? bad indentation of a mapping entry (4:11)

Comment: Hey @osman, Thanks for the note on this. Not sure what happened 9 years ago, but you're right that what was there didn't validate. I've edited it to match what I believe I had in mind and checked it with a validator. I think this provides better clarity as well.

Answer (score 18):

As noted by @Ilion, you can't have a property pointing to both a string and an object; you'd need either an array, or to give a label to your stored_proc names. Also, you keep running over your keys by using the same name, when what you really want is an array. Here's a simple example and proof that it works:

```
MY_YAML = "
access_log:
  - 
    name: getsomething
    uses:
      - some->bread
      - something else here
  -
    name: anothersp
    uses:
      - blahblah"

require 'yaml'
require 'pp'
pp YAML.load(MY_YAML)
#=> {"access_log"=>[
#=>   {"name"=>"get something", "uses"=>["some->bread", "something else here"]},
#=>   {"name"=>"anothersp", "uses"=>["blahblah"]}
#=> ]}
```

Comment: Testing provided solution in http://www.yamllint.com/ results in an error. Something is not right with the example above.

Answer (score -3):

```
---
access_log:  
  - stored_proc: getsomething    
  - uses:     
    - usedin: some->bread->crumb      
    - usedin: something else here  
    - stored_proc: anothersp      
  - uses:     
    - usedin: blahblah
reporting:
  - stored_proc: reportingsp    
  - uses:       
    - usedin: breadcrumb
```

Comment: @Brian circumvents the inability to have multiple dictionary keys with the same name by replacing every dictionary element with a single-element list containing a single-element dictionary. It makes the structure very deep and quite peculiar. Try to paste it in http://www.yamllint.com/ or somewhere and you will see more clearly how the structure really is.