# Spring read list property dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

With spring it easily possible to read a normal property using `env.getProperty(key)`

For example if your application.yaml looks like this:

```
test: "a"
```

You can read the value like this:

```
val test = env.getProperty("test")
```

But now assume you want to read the following application.yaml:

```
test:
  - 
    a: "a"
  - 
    b: "b"
```

How can I read *test[a]* **dynamically**?

What does not work unfortunately is this:

```
val test = env.getProperty("test[a]")
```

Comment: You should be reading into a `List<String>` Like this List<String> testList= env.getProperty("test"); Check if that works for you

Comment: `val test :List<String> = env.getProperty("test")` and `val test :List<String> = env.getProperty("test", List::class.java)` both do not compile. Can you be more concrete?

Comment: Not sure of this syntax, if it is specific to `kotlin` , what I mentioned should work without compilation issues!

Comment: doesn't look like a valid yaml syntax. do you want to read nested objects? If yes, you need to remove the hyphen (`-`)

Comment: Nested and yes, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8912842/3737186. That should be valid yaml. The objects are in an array!

Comment: in that case, you have a `List<Map<String, String>>` . you would need to iterate over each obj in list and find the variable

Comment: @Harsh: `List<String> testList= env.getProperty("test");` does not compile in Java because this method returns a String.

Comment: @sidgate: How would you do that in either Kotlin or Java? How can you make it read a `List<Map<String, String>>`?

Comment: `env["test[0].a"] or env["test[1].b"]` would work, but I am sure this is not what you are looking for. I would suggest to either change the yaml structure, or  map to a bean class . `@ConfigurationProperties
class ConfigProperties (val test: List<Map<String, String>>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given yaml structure would map to list of object. If you want to access the environment variables using `env` then following would work

```
val a = env["test[0].a"] // a
val b = env["test[1].b"] // b
```

Note that the objects within the list have to be accessed with index.

Alternatively, if you are using spring, you can define a `ConfigurationProperties` class and map all the values to the class variable

```
@ConfigurationProperties 
class ConfigProperties (val test: List<Map<String, String>>)
```

You can inject this class in required code and access the required property by iterating over the list

```
@Component
class TempService(val configProperties: ConfigProperties){
    fun temp(){
        val a: String = configProperties.test.firstNotNullOf { it["a"] }
    }
}
```

Ideal solution would be to change the yaml structure to normal nested object

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected. The given YAML is just a simplification of the problem.